# Issue when using grid.arrange with ggtern-generated plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, gridextra, ggtern

I recently downloaded ggtern and am trying to draw a series of ternary plots. My goal is to plot several of these on a single panel.
The documentation about ggtern says that grid.arrange works flawlessly on ggtern plots. However, my plots get messed up when I try to put them together (extra labels pop up, the labels at the corners change to T, R and L, and the lines of the ggplot2 default theme disappear (background appears homogeneously gray).
Here is my code:

```
# Ternary plot
# I want to create a plot for each level of the vector Strain_State in my dataframe called data:
lev<-levels(data$Strain_State)

# Create a list to store the plots:
plot_list=list()

# for loop to draw and store all plots at once:
for(i in 1:length(lev)){
  graph<-ggtern(data=subset(data, Strain_State==lev[i], select=c(Sex:neutral)), aes(time_pup, time_peanut, neutral)) + geom_point(size=3, aes(colour=Sex)) + ggtitle(lev[i]) + labs(x="Pup", y="Peanut butter", z="Avg.\nempty")+
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"))+
    theme(legend.title=element_text(size=18))+
    theme(legend.text=element_text(size=16))+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold",size=22))
  plot_list[[i]]<-graph
} 

plot_list[[17]] # visualize each plot individually => works fine

library(gridExtra) # visualize several plots => problematic
BW<-plot_list[1:4]
grid.arrange(plot_list[[4]], plot_list[[2]], plot_list[[1]], plot_list[[3]], nrow=2)
```

[On the left, an individual plot that looks fine, and on the right the problems I encounter when using grid.arrange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMLYk.png)

Comment: ggtern has its own exported grid.arrange, which avoids the problem you are experiencing. Either don't load `grid.arrange` package, or call `ggtern::grid.arrange(...)`

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly now!