# How to provide aesthetics to grid.arrange with ggtern?

Tags: r, ggtern

I am trying to create an image comparing two ternary plots side-by-side using [ggtern](http://www.ggtern.com/). After creating the plots, when I try to arrange them using `grid.arrange()`, I receive the following error:

```
Error: CoordTern requires the following missing aesthetics (tlr->xy) : z
```

The following code reproduces the error:

```r
library(ggtern)

plotA <- ggtern(data.frame(x = 1, y = 1, z = 1), aes(x, y, z)) + geom_point()
plotB <- ggtern(data.frame(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1), aes(a, b, c)) + geom_point()

plots <- grid.arrange(plotA, plotB, ncol = 2)
# using ggtern's arrangeGrob() throws the same error:
# plots <- arrangeGrob(plotA, plotB, ncol = 2)
```

How can I provide aesthetics to `grid.arrange()`, or otherwise fix this error so that my plots display?

Comment: Try `ggtern::grid.arrange(plotA, plotB, ncol = 2)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825983/issue-when-using-grid-arrange-with-ggtern-generated-plots

Comment: Worked perfectly - thanks @stefan! If you make that an answer I'll mark it as the preferred answer.